# Should you downvote people who are rude and mean?

Tags: discussion

If this is a place for people to help, learn, and grow, then shouldn't Stack Overflow create deterrents to being mean?

I am new here and my first question just made me feel bad about ever asking questions. I am just wondering, can I downvote due to that? Like why deter people from learn to programming?

Comment: This isn't a place to "help, learn, and grow" in the way that the rest of your question seems to mean it. It's a place to get good answers to specific, clear questions. You can learn from that, and you get help with your problems, but it's not a grade school classroom.

Comment: See also [Why do people scare off new users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253100)

Comment: No.  Otherwise, I'd have 1 rep.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a cultural issue which periodically raises its head here.

In most Western countries, the act of pointing out a mistake to someone is not considered rude.  It is just a statement of fact.
In many Eastern or Asian countries, it is considered rude.  It is more normal in these places to say things like "You would do better if..." rather than "No, do it like...".  The error is not mentioned, only the solution.

The internet, and sites such as this upon it, are open to all.  We must accept that sometimes things will be said that we may find rude but that the poster did not intend any rudeness.

It is unfortunate that you felt slighted but I'm sure no offence was intended.  If you see something that you feel is deliberately offensive, then you always have the option of flagging it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 17):

Your second question, not the first, but that's not important here.

*EJP* said:

> Well he's right and you're wrong but what's the question?

How in the heavens did you find it rude or mean? Let me tell you what have possibly gone wrong.

EJP being just a human being got overwhelmed by the amount of bold text that you used (bold usually is used to emphasize the problem) that he likely missed the actual problem that was lightly put together as *I don't know where I am going wrong* in between the text.

I would advise light composition, the least possible bold or italic texts and clearly stating what the problem/question is.

Comment: I don't know it just seemed mean to highlight the fact im wrong, something I already know. But yeah I meant to bold because I was highlighting the important points last question I asked like this I was told multiple times to use the STL , but that is the restriction. And I wrote it there but everyone ignored it and it did not help me out at all.

Comment: StackOverflow as well as most, if not all of StackExchange network allows users to "destroy" offensive posts by downvoting or flagging them for moderators' attention. As for highlights, they're OK unless you overdo them, like you did. I also couldn't let it go unnoticed that you call yourself TheGreat and you don't seem to be... so great, as in, Alexander TheGreat was a king and you... need to man up a tiny bit.

Comment: this isnt the place to start judging me or taking shots at me. Just help. So what Im sensitive does that mean Im not allowed to get the same resources or use a forum?

Comment: I did not mean to ridicule you at all. What I meant was, Internet is not a safe place despite all the measures we take to make it safer. Everyone has to develop slightly thicker skin online. The person who you claimed to be rude to you, was not rude, but rather spoke openly and directly, and that is not wrong. We as the community cannot protect everyone from everything, because there could exist a possibility that someone out there is more sensitive to reality.